# Moving files/folders based on creation date and keeping folder structure

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Windows 7 Pro environment.

I'm looking to create a batch or PowerShell script to move folders based on creation or last modified date.

The source folder is "D:\Video". The destination is "F:\DVRBackups\".

The requirement is that the folder structure be maintained, and that only folders older than a certain creation date are moved, whilst the others are left untouched.

The folder structure for the source folder looks like this:

```
D:\Video\Cam01\XXXX
D:\Video\Cam02\XXXX
D:\Video\Cam03\XXXX
```

..etc..
(XXX = hundreds of folders within the Cam01/02/03 folders spanning months)

The number of camera folders changes based on the computer DVR box i'm working on. Some locations have 5 cameras, some have as many as 35 (i.e., Cam01, Cam02, .., Cam35).

Folders from within the Cam01/02/03 folders need to be moved over to F:\DVRBackups, whilst maintaining the original folder structure.

i.e.

```
D:\Video\Cam01\0318 --> F:\DVRBackups\Video\Cam01\0318
D:\Video\Cam01\0319 --> F:\DVRBackups\Video\Cam01\0319
D:\Video\Cam02\0501 --> F:\DVRBackups\Video\Cam02\0501
```

..etc..

Can someone assist?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `robocopy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the folders within each `CamXX` folder that you need to check the Last modified time and them move. You can use the following in `PowerShell`.

```
$source = "D:\Video\"
$destination = "F:\DVRBackups\"
$date = Get-Date "25/03/2015 12:00"

dir $source | %{ dir $_.FullName | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date } | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force }
```

If you want to test what folders will be moved before hand use this command first.

```
dir $destination | %{ dir $_.FullName | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date } | select LastWriteTime, FullName }
```

This will provide a list of the all folders that will have all there content moved.